# How to choose user or page in facebook API call

Tags: node.js, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to be able to post on a Facebook page using the graph API but I am unable to as it gives me this error.

> {   message: '(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being
> installed in the group, and \\n' +
> '          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \\n' +
> '          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\n' +
> '          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \\n' +
> '          sufficient administrative permission',
> type: 'OAuthException',
> code: 200,
> fbtrace_id: 'ABHLK9ZxMynsgBhcPI3Q0DL'
> }

I am using the following API call for my request

```
const apiurl = `/${pagename}/feed`;
FB.api(apiurl, 'post', { message: req.body.fpost }, (response) => {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(!response ? 'error occurred' : response.error);
        return;
      }
      res.render('facebook');
    });
```

Can anyone help with what I am missing and how can I choose between use and page like we can choose in the Graph API Explorer as seen below. I have my page PrudentSays as the under User or Page. How can I choose the same with the API request? I have chosen all the proper permissions for posting as mentioned in the error.

[Graph API Explorer Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwer3.png)